# Customer Feedback Alternative to UserVoice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, feedback, user-feedback

We are currently hosting an ASP.NET MVC application and we wish to incorporate a turn-key customer feedback system.  [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com) will absolutely meet our needs, but we'd like to consider alternatives before moving forward.  [GetSatification](http://getsatisfaction.com/) appears to provide a similiar model. Are there any other service which we should consider as well?

Comment: Is ASP.NET platform a requirement?

Comment: We also have a platform for hosting communities around product development for free. It's built with Asp.NET MVC 4 and hosted on Azure. You can check it out at http://opentraits.com

Comment: https://productroad.com is pretty good

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd look at [IdeaTorrent](http://www.ideatorrent.org/), which is used by [Ubuntu](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/), [OLPC](http://idea.laptop.org/), and [SourceForge](http://apps.sourceforge.net/ideatorrent/sourceforge/).

Comment: I really like how IdeaTorrent looks on paper.  It's just been a long time since the last stable release, and I was hoping for a more polished product.

Comment: IdeaTorrent seems to be abandoned by developers, I wouldn't rely on such product (personal opinion).

Comment: Thanks for the info  - I have used your info in my review: http://hunchbuzz.com/buzz/alternatives-to-uservoice-getsatisfaction/

Comment: @lfaraone IdeaTorrent seems to be defunct now. Domain redirects to ad sites.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you still need some advice, I'd recommend http://idea.informer.com/. It's free and pretty efficient.

Comment: Just set up an account for my project. Looks good. Thank you for the link.

Comment: This is the best free one i've found.

Answer (score 3):

Google Moderator.

Comment: The only thing about Google Moderator, from what I can tell in testing it, is it does not provide the ability for users to discuss the question/idea/suggestion.  Other than that, it looks really good.  And it's on my Nexus One!

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at UserRules [UserRules](http://www.userrules.com)

Comment: Found it a better product thanks to its rich set of features. Liked what they've done with integrating Google Analytics and issue trackers like JIRA etc. Good UI too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not limited with hosting environment, I'd recommend to start looking in direction of [UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com/), which will be released in December, 2011. It's a self-hosted PHP customer feedback/interactive customer evaluation software that has only the best features of everything mentioned here.

It's not free, but you'll get full sourcecode and will need to pay for it only once (that's includes year of software updates).

Comment: And finally v1.0 release - http://www.useresponse.com

Comment: 1.0.1 bugfix release is now live, along with 2 new modules available as extras - Sitemap and Newsletters

Answer (score 1):

We're to set up a trello board e.g. https://trello.com/board/octopus/4e907de70880ba000079b75c

Comment: I use Trello and it is a great tool but can't see how you could use it in place of UserVoice without shoehorning it in. There is no way to set permissions at a list level which is what would be required. I don't believe there is any restrictions on voting? E.g. you can't limit users to x number of votes only. Votes do not clear automatically clear upon a card going to a specific end states (e.g. Rejected or Completed).

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.ideatorrent.org/
- http://www.eldos.com/vp/
- http://discussions.zoho.com/
- http://userecho.com/
- http://getsatisfaction.com/
- http://helprace.com/ + includes a helpdesk, knowledge base